# Can't get rid of massive white areas under the footer?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

Certain pages like the homepage and category pages have very large white sections. Wordpress and Woocommerce website.

Example:

https://www.estatediamondjewelry.com/
https://www.estatediamondjewelry.com/product-category/vintage-engagement-rings/

Tried looking for padding and margins in .site-footer and removed overflow but no luck. Also, only Gutenburg. There is no Bakery or Elementor installed. So it's no that...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go to Customise > Additional CSS and add this rule:

```
.go-to-top--vertical-pipe {
  display: none;
}
```

This element is part of your theme. Which theme are you using?

Comment: Thank you so much for trying. It didn't work though... I'm using Aurum. I cannot figure this one out.

Comment: Ok. You were definitely on the money though! I just disabled the "Go to Top" and the white doesn't show anymore... Now I need to work out how to keep it active and also not broken. This is much much closer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Assuming it is a paid theme, theme vendors generally include support for issues such as this. Suggest you contact your theme vendor for assistance.